# Google sheet COUNTA with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am using below formula in cell B2, the formula works fine, but when I try to use the formula with `arrayformula` it gives incorrect result.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",COUNTA($B$2:B2))
```

Below is the lint for the sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jaPk6MhhUxIQAvU0VPdXlWTEn0sjTdasapTkCsCma1o/edit#gid=0

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly straightforward approach:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,COUNTIFS(B2:B,"<>",ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B))))`

It basically reads "If any cell in Column B is blank, leave the return blank; otherwise count the non-blank entries in Column B including only content in rows less than or equal to the current row number."

Comment: The formula works fine and on the top its quite simple..... great thanks....

Comment: Hi Erik! Is there a reversed order version of this? Instead of outputting "1,2,3", the output would be "3,2,1".

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to explain (or better yet, illustrate in the spreadsheet) more. If you only had one item, it would be numbered `1`. But as soon as you add a second item, the *first* item (previously numbered `1`) would become `2`, and the newly added item would become `1`, etc. Is this what you want to happen: that all of the previous numbers increase by one as new line items are added, leaving the newest line item numbered `1`? If not, what?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell A1 (delete allcontent below):

```
=arrayformula({"Sr.No.";iferror(vlookup(
if(B2:B<>"",row(B2:B),),
{filter(if(B2:B<>"",row(B2:B),),if(B2:B<>"",row(B2:B),)<>""),sequence(count(if(B2:B<>"",row(B2:B),)),1)}
,2,0),)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=arrayformula(if(B2:B="",,mmult(1*(transpose(row(B2:B))<=row(B2:B)),IF(B2:B="",0,1))))
```

Comment: The formula gives the desired result... thanks